# How to use getPreviousSibling to get the node instead of getting syntax dot in ts-morph?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, ts-morph

I am currently trying to resolve the "definition" of "Identifier".

Note that I am using the `ts-morph` library.

As an example, given the following source:

```
  const fn = () => {}

  const fn2 = fn.bind(this);
```

I want to get the "definition" of `fn` Identifier (in the second line).

ts-morph is able to use "getDefinitionNodes" to get the actual `fn` function, but it does only to nodes with the type of `Identifier` and on the correct node.

So here I found the `bind` Identifier (from there I want to start).

Now I need to find the `fn` (it also can be `this.fn` sometimes).

I try to use `getPreviousSibling`, but it returns `.` (dot) and not `fn`.

Is there a better way to get the previous node instead to do `getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling()`?

```
import { Project, SyntaxKind } from "ts-morph";

console.clear();

const project = new Project();

const file = project.createSourceFile(
  "foo.ts",
  `
  const fn = () => {}

  const fn2 = fn.bind(this);
`
);

const identifiers = file.getDescendantsOfKind(SyntaxKind.Identifier);

const bind = identifiers.find((i) => i.getText() === "bind");

console.log({ bind });

const fn = bind?.getPreviousSibling();

console.log({ fn: fn?.getText() }); //<-- returns . but I was expected to fn.
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-danny-k06pdn?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer I'm working on. It has support of [template values](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/blob/master/docs/putout-script.md#__a) like `__a` and `__b`, and when you need to change the name, you just put something like `hello` in place of `__a`:

```js
export const report = () => '';

export const match = () => ({
    '__a.bind(__b)': ({__a, __b}) => {
        console.log(__a, __b);
        return true;
    }
});

export const replace = () => ({
    '__a.bind(__b)':'hello.bind(__b)',
});
```

It will output identifiers you need:

[image]

You can try it in [**Putout Editor**](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/95b7ec3073cb43f9d3803d4fb2f7c520/720b003936916cd7cf78b4039178dc9b84e7b9f3).

And produce changes:

```js
const fn = () => {}
const fn2 = hello.bind(this);
```

It much simpler then using imperative approach of searching for each previous sibling.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to handle this in ts-morph. Like you said, we can keep getting the previous sibling which navigates by token. This can be wrapped into a utility function:

```
function getPreviousSiblingUntilKindOrThrow(
  node: Node | undefined,
  kind: SyntaxKind
): Node | null {
  if (node === undefined) {
    throw new Error("node was undefined");
  }

  const previousSibling = node.getPreviousSibling();

  return previousSibling
    ? previousSibling.getKind() === kind
      ? previousSibling
      : getPreviousSiblingUntilKindOrThrow(previousSibling, kind)
    : null;
}

...

const fn = getPreviousSiblingUntilKindOrThrow(
  bind,
  SyntaxKind.Identifier
);
```

Alternatively, you can use the ancestor helpers and move up the AST and then back down:

```
const fn = bind
  ?.getFirstAncestorByKindOrThrow(SyntaxKind.PropertyAccessExpression)
  .getExpression();
```

[image: original code AST representation in ts ast viewer with the PropertyAccessExpression node highlighted]

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-morph-getprevioussiblinguntil-3urh1u?file=/src/index.ts)